# Flutter error: Each child must be laid out exactly once. On tapping on a gesture detector

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

Have started working with flutter and have encountered this problem would be glad if assisted.

Have a code like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'genderBtns_content.dart';
import 'reusableContainer_cards.dart';

const bottomContainerHeight = 80.0;
const activeCardColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
const inactiveCardColor = Color(0xFF111328);

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Color maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
  Color femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;

  void updateColor(int gender) {
    if (gender == 1) {
      if (maleCardColor == inactiveCardColor) {
        maleCardColor = activeCardColor;
        femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
      } else {
        maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
      }
    } else if (gender == 2) {
      if (femaleCardColor == inactiveCardColor) {
        femaleCardColor = activeCardColor;
        maleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
      } else {
        femaleCardColor = inactiveCardColor;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        updateColor(1);
                      });
                    },
                    child: ContainerReuse(
                      colour: maleCardColor,
                      cardChild: GenderColReuse(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                        label: 'MALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        updateColor(2);
                      });
                    },
                    child: ContainerReuse(
                      colour: femaleCardColor,
                      cardChild: GenderColReuse(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                        label: 'FEMALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          // End of Gender Cards

          Expanded(
            child: Expanded(
              child: ContainerReuse(colour: activeCardColor),
            ),
          ),

          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ContainerReuse(
                    colour: activeCardColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ContainerReuse(
                    colour: activeCardColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            color: Color(0xFFEB1555),
            width: double.infinity,
            height: bottomContainerHeight,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After running the code everything works fine until when i click on the GestureDetector.Its suppossed to change background color when tapped, it changes alright but then the background color should be removed upon tapping another GestureDetector but when another button pressed it throws an erro: "Each child must be laid out exactly once." referring to line-40 `return Scaffold` . I really need help because am still learning flutter and am stacked because of this.